# How call stored procedure to insert value in a table

Tags: insert

Please provide me sample code for inserting values in a table using stored procedure in NHibernate.

Regards
Jcreddy

Answer (score 1):

[Here is a nice example](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2006/09/18/UsingNHibernateWithStoredProcedures.aspx) from Ayende demonstrating insert using NHibenate.

Answer (score 0):

Check if this code does what you want. First you need to create the stored procedure in db.

> ALTER procedure [dbo].[ninsert]
>
> (@header AS int,@subtype AS varchar(50),@title AS varchar(50),
>   @description AS
>
> VARCHAR(50)) as insert into
>   dbo.news(nid,title,subtitle,description) values
>
> (@header,@subtype,@title,@description)

then you must access this code via your data layer in the program....

> public class datacheck
>       {
>           public SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=xxx\SQLEXPRESS;Initia Catalog=eyepax;Integrated Security=True");
>
> ```
>     public int SQLSP(string strSQL, int headerid, string subtype, string title,string descrip) // stored procedure
>     {
>         if (con.State.ToString() == "Closed")
>         {
>             con.Open();
>         }
>         //con.Open();
>
>
>         SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(strSQL, con);
>         sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
>         sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@header", headerid);
>         sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@subtype", subtype);
>         sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@title", title);
>         sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@description", descrip);
>        int results = sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
>         //sqlCmd.Dispose();
>         //con.Close();
>         return 0;
>     }
>
>
>     public DataSet executeSql()
>     {
>         DataSet ds = new DataSet();
>         if (con.State.ToString() == "Closed")
>         {
>             con.Open();
>         }
>
>         string sqlcmd1 = "select * from news";
>
>         SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlcmd1, con);
>         SqlDataAdapter sqlAda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
>         sqlAda.Fill(ds,"news");
>         return ds;
>     }
> ```
>
> public DataSet executeSql(sqlcmd)
>
> ```
> {
>     DataSet ds = new DataSet();
>     if (con.State.ToString() == "Closed")
>     {
>         con.Open();
>     }
>
>
>
>     SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlcmd, con);
>     SqlDataAdapter sqlAda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
>     sqlAda.Fill(ds,"news");
>     return ds;
> }
> ```

for insert, update delete

> public int SQLC(string strSQL) // for insert, update.delete
>           //{
>           //    if (con.State.ToString() == "Closed")
>           //    {
>           //        con.Open();
>           //    }
>           //    SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(strSQL, con);
>           //    int result = sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
>           //    return result;
>           //}